# Search Query in two table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to search query in two table(users.name, users.email, object.name)
When I type:

```
 def self.search(query)
    query = "%#{query}%"
    where("(name like ? or email like ?  or surname like ?)", query, query, query)
  end
```

It work perfectly, but Now I want to add next field to search from other table

```
def self.search(query)
        query = "%#{query}%"
        joins(:object).where("(objects.name like ? or name like ? or email like ?  or surname like ?)", query, query, query, query)
      end
```

Error:

```
`User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 120  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (1.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` INNER JOIN `objects` ON `objects`.`id` = `users`.`object_id` WHERE ((objects.name like '%ver%' or email like '%ver%' or name like '%ver%' or surname like '%ver%'))
Mysql2::Error: Column 'name' in where clause is ambiguous: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` INNER JOIN `objects` ON `objects`.`id` = `users`.`object_id` WHERE ((objects.name like '%ver%' or email like '%ver%' or name like '%ver%' or surname like '%ver%'))
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms
`
```

My model

```
User belongs_to :object
Object has_many :users
```

How Could I add other table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also specify the second names table:

```
def self.search(query)
  query = "%#{query}%"
  joins(:object).where("(objects.name like ? or users.name like ? or email like ?  or surname like ?)", query, query, query, query)
end
```